# Sequelize.js bulkCreate - Problema con mi api y db

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, sequelize

estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de cargar una serie de datos de una API local hacia mi DB. Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se inicie mi servidor, se cargue dicha data en la DB y trabajar extrayendo la data de ahí.

Mi modelo:

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
// Exportamos una funcion que define el modelo
// Luego le injectamos la conexion a sequelize.
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  // defino el modelo
  sequelize.define('Country', {
    id : {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(3), //cca3
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey : true,
      validate:{
       len: {
        args: [3, 3],
        msg: 'El campo debe tener exactamente 3 caracteres.',
      },
      
      }
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    flag: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate :{
        isIn: [[".png"]],
        isUrl: true,
      }
    },
    continent: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('South America', 'North America', 'Oceania', 'Asia', 'Antarctica', 'Europe', 'Africa'),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    capital: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    subregion: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    area:{
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    },
    population: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    }
    
  });
};
```

Mi codigo para solicitar data a la API y cargar en mi DB:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const api = ('http://localhost:5000/countries');
const {Country} = require("../models/Country")


module.exports = async() => {
    try {
        const {data} = await axios(api);

        const countries = data.map((ct) =>({
            
            id: ct.cca3,
            name: ct.name.common,
            flag: ct.flags.svg,
            continent : ct.continents[0],
            capital: ct.capital ? ct.capital[0] : "No Capital",
            subregion: ct.subregion ? ct.subregion : "No Data",
            area : ct.area,
            population: ct.population


        }
        ));       
          await Country.bulkCreate(countries);

    } catch (error) {
            return null;
    }
}
```

Hasta este punto, si yo hago console.log despues del metodo MAP, me muestra la infomación correctamente
[image: foto del console.log]

Pero cuando quiero corroborar si la data está cargada en mi DB con el SELECT * FROM "Countries";
Aparece el modelo pero sin ningun tipo de dato cargado.

Mi servidor lo inicio con este codigo:

```
const server = require("./src/server");
const { conn } = require('./src/db.js');
const loadDb = require("./src/models/loadDb.js");
const PORT = 3001;
const {countries} = require ('./src/models/loadDb.js')



conn.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  loadDb ();
  
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
})
}).catch(error => console.error(error))
```